# Serve content from different domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, azure-storage

We're moving our physical file server to cloud storage, but due to custom domain name limitations, we can't keep using the current domain for the new cloud storage.

When a request is made to:

```
https://old-subdomain.old-website.com/old-directory/image.png
```

Is it possible to preserve the user-entered URL from above in the location bar, while serving content from the cloud storage location?

```
https://new-subdomain.new-website.com/new-directory/image.png
```

The closest I've been able to achieve is a *redirect* (cannot get a *rewrite* to work) using the IIS URL Rewrite module, but this doesn't preserve the original URL:

```
<rule name="FileStorageRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^old-directory(.*)$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^old-subdomain.old-website.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://new-subdomain.new-website.com/new-directory{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

If it's possible to do what I'm asking, the solution doesn't need to be limited to using the IIS URL Rewrite module. I'm open to all solutions.

Comment: There might be hacks, but due to the way malware and virus authors have abused such mechanisms, browsers don't like it. You have legit reasons, but lots of folks would use this to do bad things.If it were my app, I'd have a little middleware piece that got the content and served it from the local domain.Doing that also ensures that a change in your cloud provider doesn't break all your stuff, just your little adapter needs modified.We recently did this for a document store of ours.

Comment: one solution might be to put content into an iframe.

Comment: if you want to serve old url and just want to change the content you can use action="rewrite" it will just change the content.